# Catchable fatal error in insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

in my code

> **Catchable fatal error**: Object of class mysqli could not be converted
>   to string in insert in phpmyadmin

```
$con = $_POST['con'];
$date =date('d-m-y');
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
$titel = $_POST['titel' ];
$by = $_POST['by'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$img = $_FILES['up']['name'];
$iim = $_FILES ['up']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file( $iim," ../Downloads");

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root','','post');
$quu  =  "INSERT INTO post1 ".
  "(email,post_by,post_titel,post_content,post_date,post_tages) ".
  "VALUES ( '{$mail}','{$by}','{$titel}','{$con}',now(),'{$tag}')";
$finsh=mysqli_query($con, $quu)
```

Comment: `'{$con}'` -> _Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string_

Answer (score 1):

You have used `$con` twice.

Both here

`$con = $_POST['con'];`

And here

`$con = mysqli_connect(...`

Just need to rename one of them. If it's the first, change the variable name in your query too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$con` (content) is overwritted by your `$con` connection object.

So you try to insert in base your own database connection

Rename your mysqli connection

Comment: mb , @rjdown was faster